# How to remove my wp website console errors?

Tags: error-handling, console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSqdY.png)
i faced these error on my wp website https://cryptophillia.com
please tell me that how can i fix these error on my website?

i need sloution about my this website https://cryptophillia.com console errors i attached sreenshot in the first row please check it and give me answer that how can i remove these errors.